# How to form Algorithm From Recurrence Relations and Find the Complexity When Negative Terms are Present

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I have seen some recurrence relations like

T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+ cn

This can be simply be converted to some algorithms . But My question here is Can the Recurrence Relations of the form

T(n)=T(n-1) - T(n-2) +cn

be converted to Algorithm / Code ? If so how ? If not why ?

What will be its complexity  ? ie
 If T(n-1) is O(n) and T(n-2) is  O(2^n) then what will be the complexity ? Will it be of O(n) or O(2^n) If so why does negative term is considered/not considered in finding the complexity

Comment: Are you possibly talking abount T(n) = T(f(n)) and T(g(n)) with f in O(n) and g in O(n^2)? I cannot see how T(n-1) could be in O(n) while T(n-2) is in O(n^2).

Comment: @BastianJ I just wanted to know how would the complexity affected when the rate of growth of negative term is higher than the positive term .

Comment: I get that, but we're talking about recursion. T is the runtime complexity. It is strictly positive for all n. 
The recurrence T(n)=T(n-1) + c means that given an Input of size n, the algorithm recursively operates on an Input of size n-1 and does some constant time stuff. An example would be Find the maximum of n elements by finding the maximum of the first (n-1) elements and compare the result to the remaining element.

Comment: That said, T(n-1)<T(n-2) would imply a decreasing complexity. That does not make any sense at all, since with such givens, you cannot have an asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Another example is merge sort, which is T(n)=T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n. Please consider every occurrence of T in the right Hand side as "applying the algorithm we analyse to a subset of size ...".

Comment: @BastianJ  Are you saying there is no algorithm of the form T(n)=T(f(n)) - T(g(n)) +c  exists ?  ie Algorithm wich contains negative terms in recurrence relations ?   Actually this is my FIRST Question .

Comment: At least, I cannot imagine how that would make any sense. Reccurrence Relations resemble the structure of the algorithm, so if I have T(n)=T(f(n)+ T(g(n)) + c, I know that the algorithm makes two recursive calls to solve an instance. Any call has a posisitve contribution to the time consumption. You cannot get spend negative time by recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Reccurrence basically is used to model that (mostly time) complexity can be written as a sum when the the algorithm is a sum of it's (partially recursive) steps.

So, for a classic divide-and conquer, you have something like 
    T(n)=2 T(n/2) + c n .

It is  possible that you have two terms like in T(n) = T(f(n))+ T(g(n) + h(n), but it is very uncommon to have T(n)=T(n-1) + T(n-2) for two reasons: 
First, when there is no non-recursive part, the algorithm would be "recursion only". I would expect at least a constant. 
Second, I can not really imagine an algorithm recursing on a (n-1)-subset and an (n-2) subset of the input.

What I cannot imagine at all is a reason to have a negative part in your recurrence equation. This would be like a part of the algorithm that contributes negative runtime. Don't see how that would be meaningful.

Comment: Yeah Sorry. I forgot to add the constant . Now edited the question

Comment: Still, you assume a recursion in which T(n-1)<T(n-2). Regardless of the Minus, this is impossible.

Comment: See a question has asked in my class test which is calculate the upper bound of  T(n)=n^2 - n^4 . Here Im confused with  will it be O(n^2)  or O(n^4) . How does this -ve term affect the total complexity of T(n) . I literally was not able to attempt it

Comment: But the Term T(n)=n^2-n^4 has absolutely no recurrence. It is negative for all n and the asymptotical behaviour is T(n) -> -\infty.
I cannot see how this is related to a recurrence for an algorithm's complexity.

Comment: i did missed a constant part  T(n)=n^2 - n^4 + c

Comment: Yet, there is no recurrence. It's a function with the same asymptotic behaviour as the dominant term. Which is -n^4.

Answer (score -1):

Apply the recursion to `T(n-1)`:

```
T(n-1) = T(n-2) - T(n-3) + c(n-1)
```

Therefore,

```
T(n) = (T(n-2) - T(n-3) + c(n-1)) - T(n-2) + cn
     = -T(n-3) + c(2n-1)
```

Apply *this* recursion to `T(n-3)`:

```
T(n-3) = -(T(n-6) + c(2(n-3) - 1)) + c(2n-1)
       = -T(n-6) - c(2n - 7) + c(2n - 1)
       = -T(n-6) + 6c
```

Finally,

```
T(n) = T(n-6) + 6c
```

or `T(n) = O(n)`

Comment: Please try to answer specific to the questions . Thanks

Comment: Your question is unspecific. User58697 solved the equation. It is impossible to mix this equation with an assumption linke T(n-1) in O(n) but T(n-2) not in O(n). T AS a function is vor ia not in O(n).

Comment: Also, I have to add that @user58697's solution is not correct. It has as intermediate T(n)=-T(n-3)+c(n) [which to me proves that there is no asymptotic behaviour]. He/she gets rid of it by applying the equation to itself, yielding T(n)=T(n-6)+2c(n).
This is like having x(n)=-x(n-1)+c, and concluding x(n)=x(n-2)+2c. While the latter has a solution x(n)=cn, it is clearly not a solution of the former.